# How to use read and write for knockout computed property in coffescript

Tags: coffeescript, knockout-2.0

I will highly appreciate any help. I can't write properly read & write for computed property in CoffeeScript.

```
@allChecked = ko.computed => {
  read: ()->
    console.log 'allChecked->read()'
    firstUnchecked = ko.utils.arrayFirst @contactGroups(), (item) ->
                      item.IsSelected() == false
    firstUnchecked == null
  write: (value)->
    console.log 'allChecked->write()', value
    g.IsSelected(value) for g in @contactGroups()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just blindly guessing here, because I don't have access to the rest of your code.

## First

`ko.computed` takes either a read function, or takes an object which has `read` and `write` functions. It doesn't take a function which returns an object with `read` / `write` properties.

***Examples***

**right** : `ko.computed -> 5`

**right** : `ko.computed { read: -> 5 }`

**wrong** : `ko.computed -> { read: -> 5 }`

## Second

`@` strictly means `this`, which means depending on how a function is called (`f()`, `f.apply(_)`, `new F()`), it could have different values. If you want to specific the value of `this`, you can specify the `owner` when creating the `ko.computed`.

```
computed = ko.computed {
  read: -> @getValue()
  owner: @
}
```

***Examples***

**good**

```
class Thing
  constructor: (@number) ->
    self = @
    ko.computed -> self.number
```

**ko-way**

```
class Thing
  constructor: (@number) ->
    ko.computed {
      read: -> @number
      owner: @
    }
```

**bad**

```
class Thing
  constructor: (@number) ->
    ko.computed -> @number # means this.number
```

**confusing** *(=>)*

```
class Thing
  constructor: (@number) ->
    ko.computed => @number
```

## Finally

Putting it all together.

***Example***

```
@allChecked = ko.computed {
  read: ->
    console.log 'allChecked->read()'
    firstUnchecked = ko.utils.arrayFirst @contactGroups(), (item) ->
                      item.IsSelected() == false
    firstUnchecked == null

  write: (value) ->
    console.log 'allChecked->write()', value
    group.IsSelected(value) for group in @contactGroups()

  owner: @
}
```